# Trouble working with date indexes with Multi-Index

Tags: pandas

I am trying to understand how the date-related features of indexing in `pandas` work.

If I have this data frame:

```
dates = pd.date_range('6/1/2000', periods=12, freq='M')
df1 = DataFrame(randn(12, 2), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

I know that we can extract records from 2000 using `df1['2000']` or a range of dates using `df1['2000-09':'2001-03']`.

But suppose instead I have a dataframe with a multi-index

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([dates, list('HIJKHIJKHIJK')], names=['date', 'id'])
df2 = DataFrame(randn(12, 2), index=index, columns=['C', 'D'])
```

Is there a way to extract rows with a year 2000 as we did with a single index? It appears that `df2.xs('2000-06-30')` works for accessing a particular date, but `df2.xs('2000')` does not return anything. Is `xs` not the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `xs` for this, but you can index using `.loc`.
One of the example you tried, would then look like `df2.loc['2000-09':'2001-03']`. The only problem is that the 'partial string parsing' feature does not work yet when using multi-index. So you have to provide actual datetimes:

```
In [17]: df2.loc[pd.Timestamp('2000-09'):pd.Timestamp('2001-04')]
Out[17]:
                      C         D
date       id
2000-09-30 K  -0.441505  0.364074
2000-10-31 H   2.366365 -0.404136
2000-11-30 I   0.371168  1.218779
2000-12-31 J  -0.579180  0.026119
2001-01-31 K   0.450040  1.048433
2001-02-28 H   1.090321  1.676140
2001-03-31 I  -0.272268  0.213227
```

But note that in this case `pd.Timestamp('2001-03')` would be interpreted as `2001-03-01 00:00:00`(an actual moment in time). Therefore, you have to adjust the start/stop values a little bit.

A selection for a full year (eg `df1['2000']`) would then become `df2.loc[pd.Timestamp('2000'):pd.Timestamp('2001')]` or `df2.loc[pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01'):pd.Timestamp('2000-12-31')]`

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps this should be a separate question, but how would I select any rows with `id=H` without regard to date?

Comment: ``df2.loc[(slice(None), 'H'),:]``. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers