# Using slicers with MultiIndex in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to use a slicer on a pandas dataframe with a MultiIndex:

```
dates = pd.date_range('6/30/2000', periods=12, freq='M')
index = MultiIndex.from_arrays([dates, list('HIJKHIJKHIJKHIJK')], names=['date', 'id'])
df = DataFrame(randn(12, 4), index=index, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

I would like to get the rows where `id='H'`. From [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125674/trouble-working-with-date-indexes-with-multi-index/30125850?noredirect=1#comment48523693_30125850) in a related question I asked, and from reading [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers), I thought this:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), 'H'),:]
```

or perhaps this:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), ['H']),:]
```

would work. The first one returns this error:

> IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 12

and the second one gives this error:

> IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

From looking at other questions, I thought perhaps I need to sort by the 2nd-level index before trying to slice. I'm not really sure what I'm doing here, but I tried to use `df.sort_index()` but am having trouble with the syntax. I'm also not sure whether that is even the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a problem in your line

```
index = MultiIndex.from_arrays([dates, list('HIJKHIJKHIJKHIJK')], names=['date', 'id'])
```

The arrays should be the same length. This not raising is probably a bug.

If you fix that then either of

```
In [58]: df.xs('H', level='id')
Out[58]:
                   A         B         C         D
date
2000-06-30 -0.645203  0.965441  0.150037 -0.083979
2000-10-31 -1.222954  0.498284 -1.249005 -1.664407
2001-02-28 -0.941248  2.025381  0.450256  1.182266

In [59]: df.loc[(slice(None), 'H'), :]
Out[59]:
                      A         B         C         D
date       id
2000-06-30 H  -0.645203  0.965441  0.150037 -0.083979
2000-10-31 H  -1.222954  0.498284 -1.249005 -1.664407
2001-02-28 H  -0.941248  2.025381  0.450256  1.182266
```

should work, depending on whether you'd like to drop the `id` level.

Comment: Doh! Thanks. I see you've already opened this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10127).